# Retrieving specific direct message information via PHP using API 1.1

Tags: php, twitter

I'm hoping you can help as I think I'm missing a trick here and can't find where I'm going wrong. I am looking to retrieve a few specific pieces of info from Twitter DMs via PHP. I've written some code to pull through what I'm after, but when running the script, only the message (tweet), ID, and date sent are pulling through. The rest like user name etc... remains blank. The current output can be found here: http://anonytine.hol.es/TDM94.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
  <?php
echo "<h2>Simple Twitter API Test</h2>";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php'); 


$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "XXXX",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXXX",
'consumer_key' => "XXXX",
'consumer_secret' => "XXXX"
);
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json';
$getfield = '?since_id=240136858829479935&count=20';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

echo "<h3>Direct Messages</h3>";          
foreach($string as $items)
  {
    echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
    echo "Message ID: ".$items['id']."<br />";
    echo "Tweet: ".$items['text']."<br />";
    echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
    echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
    echo "Location: ". $items['user']['geo_enabled']."<br />";
    echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
    echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";
  }
{

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/direct_messages/new you should

be calling the following end point

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json

The element names are different than what you are using.

For the

```
$items['user']['name']
```

its

```
$items['sender']['name']
```

and so on

In the new api call https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json

check the returned array how data is returned before doing loop.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, but my confusion has grown as I was referring to this more recent doc: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/direct_messages

Comment: hmm can u post your array in your question ? This will help to check the issue.

Comment: I've amended the question to include all the info and a link to the current coded output. Thanks for your help with this. It'd probably help if Twitter removed exhausted reference from their site tbh.

Comment: well you have posted the output you got from looping the data. Can u print_r($string) and post the output ?

Comment: Apologies Abhik but I'm a bit of a novice with PHP and have more fumbled through the code piecing this together. Where exactly do you want me to paste the print_r($string) in the code? Is the complete code above not enough? Sorry for the Qs

Comment: just do a print_r($string), then on the browser you can see view and copy that array in your question on in http://codepad.org/

Comment: I'm sorry Abhik, I can't get it and need to shoot off for now. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: With your help and a little bit of tinkering, I've got it sorted, thank you :-)